# Having problems with getting arrays into arrays for json-encode

Tags: php, arrays, json

heres the function:
http://pastebin.com/tQLjzzbH

I want it to return this:

```
{"years":[
    {
        "yName":"2011",
        "yAlbums:[
            {
                auID:"1234",
                aID:"456",
                etc..
            },
            {
                auID:"12345",
                aID:"4567",
                etc..
            }
    },
    {
        "yName":"2010",
        "yAlbums:[
            {
                auID:"2234",
                aID:"556",
                etc..
            }
    }
]}
```

but its only returning this:

```
{"years":[
{"yName":"2011"},
{"yName":"2010"}]}
```

Been trying to get this for ages, am totally lost now. Some help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have read your result to the very end by

```
while($data2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $yearsArrayRaw[] = $data2['album_year'];
}
```

Add `mysql_data_seek($result,0)` before inner `while`, to line 36. Also, I would suggest rewriting this function to have single loop, using something like

```
$year_albums= array();
while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    if (empty($years[$data['album_year']])){
        $year_albums[$data['album_year'] = array(
            'yName'=>$data['album_year'],
            'yAlbums'=>array()
        );
     }
     //...album creation logic here...//
     $year_albums[$data['album_year']['yAlbums'][] = $album;
}
//Converting arrays into objects
$years = array();
foreach ($year_albums as $year){
    $years[] = (object)$year;
}
json_encode($years);
```

Comment: mysql_data_seek fixed it :), true the function does need rewriting, but doing it along the lines you suggested will not exactly work given you don't know the input data. But Thanks a lot all the same :)